# Bulk Edit on Modern Experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, modern-experience

Using the bulk edit to bulk edit to change the content type  of files and folders.

I'm using this feature to change the content type of multiple folders, which worked perfectly fine .
Unfortunately, the content type of the subfolder is not changing.

Is this normal, maybe the bulk feature only includes the  items on the surface and no subfolder.

Is there any way to change the content type of subfolder when using Modern Experience on Document Library

Answer (score 0):

Just as you said, the bulk edit does not affect subfolders. If you want to change content type of subfolder in bulk, flow will be a good choice. 
[image]

It works in my end which find all the folders in the document library and change the content type to a custom content type in update file property action.